# Internal system error occurred while registering in DSpace

Tags: dspace

New user registration stopped working. Gives the message: "Internal system error"  in DSpace.
Previously registered users can log into their account.
What could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: An internal server error means, that some error within DSpace or dependencies of it occurred. You should take a look into the log file `dspace.log`, which probably contains more information. If you find something there, you might add it to your question. Without these information, it is rather unlikely that anyone can help you. Please be careful to not post sensible information out of your `dspace.log`. And please specify which version of DSpace and which of DSpace's UIs you are using.

Comment: Alas, we currently do not have a specialist. Our Repository - http://lib.pnu.edu.ua:8080

Comment: We will not be able to help without getting access to the messages DSpace logs into the file I mentioned. I send an email to the mail address on your repository's home page to get into closer contact.